# clickable imageview and buttonview in a cell(UITableView or collectionView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad, collectionview

I have a UI design problem about ios objective-c. there are thousands of product images need to be displayed in a single page,5 products every line,and 2 lines information for each product under each image. If user clicks the product image, I need to add it to shopping cart. moreover,I need to add a small button under each product image.If user click the button, I will display a window to allow user to write notes for that product.

How to design this kind of UI? thank you.

Comment: Just add the button as a subview that's what you meant?

Comment: how to know which button and which image is clicked?

Comment: Swift or objective?

Comment: Do you understand my answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
cell.yourImageView.tag = ip.row;
cell.youreImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapClick:)];
// this maybe repeat to addGesture
// you can user custom UITableViewCell to avoid it
[cell.youreImageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];


- (void)tapClick:(id)sender
{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = sender;
    UIView *view = tap.view;
    if (view.tag == 0) {
        // row 1
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath:
ip is `indexPath`

```
cell.btn.tag = ip.row;
[cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnclk:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Go to view controller and add this function which will be called every time any button will be called... Each button has unique tag (because of the raw numbers) and so you can make condition to each one by its number...

```
-(void)btnclk:(UIButto*)sender
{
     if (sender.tag == 0) 
      // btn clicked from cell number 0
}
```

I wrote it from my iPhone so I will write more when I get to a PC...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code :

```
UIButton*btnLink;//create button

btnLink=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 8, self.view.frame.size.width, 77)];//set frame

[btnLink setTitle:[@"yourTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

btnLink.tag = indexPath.row;//set tag 

[btnLink addTarget:self action:@selector(linkClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];//set action

[cell addSubview:btnLink];



-(IBAction)linkClick:(id)sender{

UIButton *btnSender = sender;

NSLog(@"btnSender.tag====>%ld",(long)btnSender.tag);//check your clicked button tag number

NSDictionary *dS;

dS= [yourArray objectAtIndex:btnSender.tag];

NSString*myurl=[dS objectForKey:@"link"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"yourURL OR ANYTHING"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```